# Firestore v9 - get a document ref from collection ref and vice versa

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Sometimes I have a one or the other of a reference to a `Document` or a `Collection`. I would like to be able to code a ref to the other using the first as a stepping stone. I could easily to it in v8 but there is no documentation for a similar operation in v9. At least that I can find.
For e.g.,

```
const collRef = collection(db, "users", userId, "books", bookId, "characters");
```

I would like to this:

```
const docRef = doc(db, collRef, characterId);
```

Instead of this:

```
const docRef = doc(db, "users", userId, "books", bookId, "characters", characterId);
```

Is this possible?  If not, what would the correct syntax be?

Comment: You can't make a document reference using a where clause.  A document reference must be the full path of a specific document using its ID. A where clause only works if you intend to execute a query.

Comment: Noted.  Question edited to suit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [API documentation for doc()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#doc_2) suggests that you can do this:

```
const docRef = doc(collRef, characterId);
```

You don't provide `db` as the first argument.

Comment: Ahhh.  Let me try that.

Comment: I take it that this would also work? `const docRef = doc(collRef, characterId, "scenes", sceneId)`?

Comment: Why don't you give it a try?